# How to make this base class work with Entity Framework 6.1 code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a base class that looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CreatedByUserId { get; set; }
    public int ModifiedByUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedByUserId")]
    public virtual User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModifiedByUserId")]
    public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to use this class as the base for every other class. Also for the User class, because users are created and modified by other users.

```
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

But I get this error:

*The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.*

I researched the error, and it all became quite clear. EF has to be told how these entities relate to eachother, and which entity to save first, and which comes second. But among all the examples/solutions, I did not find any similar case. Can anyone help me out with this? I'd prefer to have this fixed by using data annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know any good solution for this with data annotation but using Fluent API can help you in a very clear way. You should override OnModelCreating method in your DbContext class

```
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasRequired<User>(x => x.CreatedBy)
                .WithMany();

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasRequired<User>(x => x.ModifiedBy)
                .WithMany();
        }
    }
```

That's how you could describe two self-referencing one-to-many relationship.

Comment: Thanks, That works. Still curious on whether this can be done with data annotations though.

Comment: @Tys, to describe one-to-many relationship with data annotations you should create a collection on "one"-side.You can try to add something like `List<BaseEntity> EntitiesCreatedByUser` property with attribute `[InverseProperty("CreatedBy")]`  and `List<BaseEntity> EntitiesModifiedByUser` with `[InverseProperty("ModifiedBy")]` to the User class. But then you need to move Id property to your BaseEntity to make it works and then enforce EF to create TPC scheme instead of default TPH. I can update answer if you want but I'm still not sure that it will work correct.Also I think it looks to complex

Comment: You are right, we better leave it like this. I'll just drop my 'annotations only' requirement. Don't want to make my model more complex just because of this. The fluent API does quite a nice job.